# The Laravel log path has not been updated

Tags: php

I changed the path to the larval log in the config folder, but the logs are not updated in project.log. PHP-fpm to start the service and in that config file also have updated the files it is not working can you help with this please see my below code.

```
return [

    'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),

    'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['daily'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],

        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravelkd.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],

        'daily' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravelkd.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'days' => 14,
        ],

        'slack' => [
            'driver' => 'slack',
            'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
            'username' => 'Laravel Log',
            'emoji' => ':boom:',
            'level' => 'critical',
        ],

        'papertrail' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'level' => 'debug',
            'handler' => SyslogUdpHandler::class,
            'handler_with' => [
                'host' => env('PAPERTRAIL_URL'),
                'port' => env('PAPERTRAIL_PORT'),
            ],
        ],

        'stderr' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
            'formatter' => env('LOG_STDERR_FORMATTER'),
            'with' => [
                'stream' => 'php://stderr',
            ],
        ],

        'syslog' => [
            'driver' => 'syslog',
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],

        'errorlog' => [
            'driver' => 'errorlog',
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
    ],
    'rollbar' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => \Rollbar\Laravel\MonologHandler::class,
            'access_token' => env('ROLLBAR_TOKEN'),
            'level' => 'debug',
     ],

];
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: May be your config files are cached and new changes are not reflecting try once `php artisan optimize:clear` command.